# Agregar una condicion mas en mi codigo datatables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datatables

Buenos días quisiera entender, necesito ayuda de como poder agregar una condición mas en mi codigo de data tables ya que no lo hacer que muestre otro tipo de color si es mayor o menor a una cantidad de una variable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
{
               targets: 15,
               sortable: false,

               createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){

                    if (parseInt (rowData[15]) <= 10){
                         $(td).html(" <span class='badge bg-danger'>Produc. Vencido</span>")
                     }else{
                         $(td).html(" <span class='badge bg-success'>"+parseInt (cellData)+" Días x vencer</span>")
                         
                    
                       
                       
                    
                
                         }

                    }
               },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que cuando le agrego un if y luego un elseif y esle no me arroja nada no entiendo como hacer
algo parecido a esto para que cuando este en rojo salga vencido , amarillo por vencer y los numeros y en verde dias faltantes (dias)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi estoy sacando de la base de datos en un procedimiento almacenado para poder restar 2 fechas y sacar en una variable DIAS

```js
SELECT   '' as detalles,
                                                    id,
                                                    codigo_producto,
                                                    id_categoria_producto,
                                                    nombre_categoria,
                                                    descripcion_producto,
                                                    ROUND(precio_compra_producto,2) as precio_compra_producto,
                                                    ROUND(precio_venta_producto,2) as precio_venta_producto,
precio_mayor_producto,
precio_oferta_producto,
                                                    ROUND(utilidad,2) as utilidad,
                                                    case when c.aplica_peso = 1 then concat(stock_producto,' Kg(s)')
                                                        else concat(stock_producto,' Und(s)') end as stock_producto,
                                                    case when c.aplica_peso = 1 then concat(minimo_stock_producto,' Kg(s)')
                                                        else concat(minimo_stock_producto,' Und(s)') end as minimo_stock_producto,
                                                    case when c.aplica_peso = 1 then concat(ventas_producto,' Kg(s)') 
                                                        else concat(ventas_producto,' Und(s)') end as ventas_producto,
                                                    fecha_vencimiento_producto,
                                                    DATEDIFF(fecha_vencimiento_producto, fecha_creacion_producto) as dias ,
                                                    '' as acciones
                                                    FROM productos p INNER JOIN categorias c on p.id_categoria_producto = c.id_categoria order by p.id DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los resultados todo este codigo lo saque de un tutorial por internet MVC sistema pos y le estoy agregando algunas cosas mas pero quisiera entender de como agregar esas 3 condiciones soy novato por eso recurro a su ayuda. Gracias de ante mano no se si tengo que motras otro tipo de codigo

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que será algo como esto:

```
if (parseInt (rowData[15]) <= 10){
   $(td).html(" <span class='badge bg-danger'>Produc. Vencido</span>")
}
else if(parseInt (rowData[15]) <= 25){
   $(td).html(" <span class='badge bg-warning'>"+parseInt (cellData)+" Días x vencer</span>")
} else{
   $(td).html(" <span class='badge bg-success'>"+parseInt (cellData)+" Días x vencer</span>")
}
```

Asi, los que sean menor o igual a `10` salen `rojos`, los que esten entre `11` y `25` salen `amarillos`, de lo contrario salen `verdes`.